# Tests are not running in order

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, visualstudio

Why are tests not running in the order that is set inside test suite in Visual Studio Online?

We have Microsoft Visual Team Services builds, Visual Studio Test Agent is deployed to virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

VSTS builds and test runs will not run tests in a specific order unless you create Ordered Tests in your test suite.

If your Visual Studio Online subscription doesn't include Ordered Tests, you may not be able to specify an order for your tests.

Comment: How I create Ordered Tests in my test suite in Visual Studio Online?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Please, how to include Ordered Tests into Visual Studio Online subscription ?

Comment: Or how to find out if Visual Studio Online subscription include Ordered Tests ? And how to set up?

Comment: And what in the case that I add tests to the ordered test and in the Test Assembly field I replace default value: **\*test*.dll
by value: **\*.orderedtest

Is it possible ?
Is it possible to run ordered tests in the Visual Studio Online ?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with the link above and looking through the site.

Comment: It is not working. I've created a OrderedTests and I have added tests in the required order. But tests have been run in different order :(

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to run tests in specific order in VSO ?